# Not Seeding Correctly Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to seed the db using model methods but it isn't populating the fields correctly.  First off, my seed data looks like this:

```
5.times do
  @battery = Battery.create
end

pan1 = Pan.create(battery_id: Battery.first.id, date: '2019-01-02', reading: 8.0, amount: nil, advisement: 700, acceptance: 87.5)

15.times do
  Pan.create(battery_id: Battery.first.id, date: pan1.date += 3.days, reading: Pan.reads, amount: Pan.ratings, advisement: Pan.advise, acceptance: Pan.accept, accepted: nil)
end
```

Now the first problem I'm seeing in the database from this is that panel1 is being created, however, reading, acceptance are both showing nil instead of the preset values I have tried to define.  Where is my error in this?  Here all the methods that are being used in the model:

```
class Pan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :battery

  def self.reads
    @pans = Pan.all
    @pans.each do |pan|
      if pan.reading == nil && pan.date >= 1.week.ago
        pan.update_attributes!(reading: rand(5.0..18.0))
      else
        pan.update_attributes!(reading: nil)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.ratings
    @pans = Pan.all
    @pans.each do |pan|
      pan.update_attributes!(amount: rand(200..20000))
    end
  end

  def self.advise
    @pans = Pan.all
    @pans.each do |pan|
      if pan.reading != nil && (pan.reading < 9.0 || pan.reading > 14.0)
        pan.update_attributes!(advisement: rand(200..20000))
      end
    end
  end

  def self.accept
    @pans = Pan.all
    @pans.each do |pan|
      if pan.reading != nil && pan.amount != nil
        accepted = pan.amount/pan.reading
      elsif pan.reading != nil && pan.advisement != nil
        accepted = pan.advisement/pan.reading
      end

      pan.update_attributes!(acceptance: accepted)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm attempting to update attributes one at a time through each method, then calling it in the seed file.  Is this a good way to go about doing it?

The two questions I have from this is why pan1 isn't seeding correctly, when I create just panel1 by itself, reading and acceptance are set to their predefined values, but when I add the 15.times do, they get set to null?

Secondly, in self.reads, I'm attempting to update that field only if it's been over a week since the last reading, and only if that field is nil.  Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Do you have any items in DB after seeding? Have you tried to replace `create` with `create!` in your seed file? It will raise an exception if the record is invalid and cannot be created.

Comment: Because you are setting it to nil after each one is created. `pan.update_attributes!(reading: nil)`

Comment: I tried taking the else off thinking it was the problem, however, even in that case it's not populating reading.  Is there a different way to generate a random decimal?

Comment: The create! did not stop it from being created.  Yes there are files in the DB.

Comment: in your `self.reads` method, is `@pan` singular a typo ? because you iterate next on `@pans` plural

Comment: Typo was here, I corrected it.  It was written correctly in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that all the class methods `self.reads` `self.ratings` `self.advise` `self.accept` end with the result of an `each` method, the result of an each is always the original array and you're trying to assign an array in this fields `reading: Pan.reads, amount: Pan.ratings, advisement: Pan.advise, acceptance: Pan.accept`

Second problem is that all those methods update all the records of `Pan` model, so when you call the `15.times` block, this methods update the original result of `pan`